# MySQL Workbench: How to define 2 foreign key relationships (A,B) and (B,C) for a table with 3 primary keys (A,B,C)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set up a MySQL model in MySQL Workbench.

So far, I have defined three tables: `studentTerm`, `studentTermCourse`, `courseTerm`.  The table `studentTermCourse` has 3 primary keys: `{studentId, courseCode and termCode`, where `studentId` and `courseCode` are primary keys for the `studentTerm` table and `courseCode` and `termCode` are primary keys for the `courseTerm` one.

I am trying to define the foreign keys in the `StudentTermCourse`, but am unable to select `termCode` in the foreign key name in relation to the `courseTerm` table, given that I have already defined it as a foreign key in relation to the `studentTerm` table.

I hope the screenshot below makes it more clear:

Could you please advise the correct method to define the primary/foreign keys?

Thanks.
[image: EER diagram of tables and foreign key studenttermcourse_courseterm]
[image: foreign key studenttermcourse_studentterm]

Comment: It might have something to do with the key order. Have you tried `courseCode` then `termCode` in `courseTerm`?

Comment: @DaveCoast Thank-you for your response.  In implementing your suggestion, I realised the real problem - I had termCode as unsigned in the other two tables (i.e. studentTerm and studentTermCourse) but not in courseTerm.  (Just starting out again with SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure columns in the two tables are exactly the same datatype (e.g. unsigned)